# Getting value coded of domain from map layer with arcgis javascript api

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, domains

I'm trying to read domain values on a map, how to achieve this objective in arcgis javascript api? any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get this from the `FeatureLayer` class. There is an attribute called `fields`, which is an array of [`Field`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/field-amd.html) objects. The [`Field`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/field-amd.html) class has `domain` attribute.

The following will output the domains in the console (if any):

```
var map = new Map(...);
var fl = new FeatureLayer(...);
map.addLayer(fl);

// when layer is ready
fl.on("load", ()=>{
   for (var i = 0; i < fl.fields.length; i++) {
     console.debug(fl.fields[i].domain);
   }
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks janechii, I tried your code before, and it keeps telling me f1.fields is undefined? what might be the problem? I'm new to arcgis api :(
this is my code:
var f1=  new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Petroleum/KGS_OilGasFields_Kansas/MapServer/0", {
   mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
   outFields:["*"]
   });
  
for (var i = 0; i < f1.fields.length; i++) {    alert(f1.fields[i].domain);
}

Comment: Cool! what was the issue? And a little tip, you should try to use the AMD style as much as possible. Not sure when they'll phase out the old style.

Comment: I'm not sure what was the issue, but what I did was that I moved the line alert(f1.fields[i].domain); after I added the layer to the map, after this line map.addlayers[{f1}];
Ok, I'll take your advice and start using the AMD style, Thnks a lot.

Comment: You're right! I forgot to add the layer to the map. Also, it is asynchronously loading the layer's details, so you have to make sure that the layer info is ready before you find its domains.

Answer (score 0):

at v3.12, try to use getDomain, fl.getDomain("fieldName")
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#getdomain